# How to deal with rows in fact table that don't have matching value in date dimension, ssas cube?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, data-warehouse, cube

I a new to this site and to SSAS in general. I am currently doing some "on the job training" trying to put together an SSAS cube and I am experiencing some problems.

When I try to process the Cube it fails. This happens due to the fact that the Fact table used for the cube contains some 13 rows that have dates that are outside of the range of the Date dimension that I am using.

I am not sure what I should do to get around/fix this.

Exclude the rows?

Change the dimension?

I have tried to find an answer to this on my own, but it seems that my phrasing of the issue/problem has so far stopped me from finding relevant information.

Any advice or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

/Chriss

Comment: *Why* are the dates out of range? Is it because they're preposterously wrong?

Comment: The fact table contains rows that precedes and exceeds that which exists in the date dimension. The date dimension was built for use with other fact tables, I am just reusing it.

Comment: Yeah, but my question is whether, in business/logical/whatever terms, those dates are obviously *wrong* or not. How you fix your problem depends on that, to some degree. Only *you* (or your users) know what this out of range data means -- it may mean that your dimension table needs extending, it may mean that the data is so senseless that you should ignore the entire row, it may mean that a user has mistyped a date but not for an *important* data item, so you could bring the row in but fix up the date in some way, e.g. use a sane default value and add it to an exception report for fixing.

Comment: Ok I see, well the dates make sense and are correct. And as you suggested that could mean that the dimension table needs extending. I am going to try and do just that and see how it works! Thank you for your input Matt!